# What to return after $response->send() in Symfony2 controller?

Tags: php, symfony, return

If I prepare a response in my controller like so:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($this->render('mytemplate.html.twig');
$response->send();
```

Rather than using:

```
return $this->return('mytemplate.html.twig');
```

Then I haven't actually returned anything... what should I do after $response->send()? Should I just return true?

Comment: Or remove `$response->send();` and return `$response`

Comment: That prints the headers

Comment: No it doesn't*. My bad.

Comment: It does send headers, but it does not stop script execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You must return response**

From symfony documentation:

> The goal of a controller is always the same: create and return a Response object.

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function helloAction()
{
    return new Response('Hello world!');
}
```

Another example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

$content = $this->renderView(
    'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig',
    array('name' => $name)
);

return new Response($content);
```

You can read about it here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html

Comment: This is correct, thanks. I was using render and not renderView when setting my response's content, so it kept printing the headers when I returned the response.

Comment: You don't have to return a response if you use the `@Template()` annotation - then all you need to return is an array of view data.